# Is there a difference between the wedge product and the exterior product?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, exterior-algebra

I haven't been able to find much on the internet regarding this distinction (if there is one). I suspect they might be different, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference: "wedge product" and "exterior product" are synonyms (at least in the context of exterior algebras and differential forms).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!